# how to open tcp/ip properties from cmd or run directly?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Is there anyone knows that how to open tcp/ip ver 4 properties from cmd or run directly?

I mean the window that you can setup your ip, gateway dns...i want to make a shortcut of ip properties or open it from cmd

Did some research, looks like there is nothing like `appwiz.cpl` can open that ip setup window directly.....

Any idea?

PS: I need to know the way to open that ip setup GUI window from cmd or run.

This is the best answer i found, but it is still not opening that ip setup window directly, you still have to click couple times....

Use this to get your NIC number:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards"
```

Then to get your NIC GUID

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\YourCardNumber
```

Then do this:

```
start ::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}\::{Network Adapter GUID}
```

this actually just like `ncpa.cpl`

But it is still not opening that ip setup GUI window directly.....

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to open up that specific property window directly. There's only a shortcut to the "generic" interfaces screen, being `ncpa.cpl`.

You can however use `netsh` from cmd to directly set or view the properties. For instance, if you want to set the IP address of your "Local Area Connection" (default name for the primary network interface) to `192.168.0.5`, with a subnet of `255.255.255.0` and a gateway of `192.168.0.1`, you would use:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection"
source=static address=192.168.0.5 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.0.1
```

For an overview of all possible options, use:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address /?
```

To view the current configuration, you can use:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show addresses "Local Area Connection"
```

Which would then show:

```
Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"

DHCP enabled:                         No
IP Address:                           192.168.0.5
Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.0.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
Default Gateway:                      192.168.0.1
Gateway Metric:                       0
InterfaceMetric:                      10
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough, i know how to setup ip from command line, I want to know the way that i can open that ip setup GUI window....not setup ip from cmd. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: @user3303155 Yeah, just noticed that. There is no way to open up that specific property window directly. There's only a shortcut to the "generic" interfaces screen, being ncpa.cpl.

Comment: I edited my question a bit, there is a way to open, but still need to click couple times....so sad....

Comment: The first line of code is demonstrated incorrectly as this is a **1-liner command**. For instance, using default LAN IP (*or bridge mode 192.168.1.1 static IP*) is `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="NeTwOrK-NaMe" source=static address=192.168.1.2 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.1.1` while going back to DHCP is `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="NeTwOrK-nAmE" source=dhcp`. You guys need to let readers know how to literally use it for them to change anything else afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use AutoHotKey for this? This is the script I use:

```
Run ncpa.cpl 
WinWaitActive Network Connections
SendInput {Tab 4}{Right}!{Enter} ; change {Tab 4} to suit the position of your specific connection in the Connections list
WinWaitActive Wireless Network Connection Properties ; change the title if necessary, for example, if you're on LAN.
SendInput {Down 4}!r
```

Comment: interesting software, I will try it.

Comment: Does not work. The information provided isn't clear enough as to how to *select* a network within `ncpa.cpl` and then to specifically open up the **IPv4** options for the network selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did.. while there is not direct CLSID for IPV4 properties, i did come up with this script for those who need it:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`reg query 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards"`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%


for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "%var%"  /V ServiceName  ^|findstr /ri 
"REG_SZ"') DO (
SET ServiceName=%%a
)
ECHO %ServiceName%
explorer shell:::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2- 
00805FC1270E}\::%ServiceName%
```

Comment: Strange thing: Have 3 physical ethernet adapters in my PC. When assemble batch file from your lines of code, it open "Interface properties" tab for one adapter but "Interface Status" tab for two adapters. Anyone have explanation for such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It is really helpful. But what will the GUID for NIC teaming if combination of 2 or more NICs. And traffic is going through TEAMS Network?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1219414)